# I can't insert a footnote into the copied text

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, tinymce

I'm making a way for users to insert a footnote in the text (as implemented in scientific articles). I'm using tinymce for this, and it functions as a plugin. It works fine when I type the text itself. But as soon as I try to insert a footnote with it into the copied text (that is, I copied text from another site and want to insert a footnote), it gives me an error - **Uncaught ReferenceError: $node is not defined**

I've already tried many attempts, but I can't get it to work. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**footnote.min.js**

```
! function () {
   "use strict";
   var t, e = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.PluginManager");
   "function" != typeof Array.prototype.forEach && (Array.prototype.forEach = function (t) {
      for (var e = 0; e < this.length; e++) t.apply(this, [this[e], e, this])
   }), Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent") && !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent").get && (t = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerText"), Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "textContent", {
      get: function () {
         return t.get.call(this)
      },
      set: function (e) {
         return t.set.call(this, e)
      }
   }));
   var n = function (t, e) {
         var n = t;
         for (var o in e) n = n.replace(/\{(\/?[^\}]+)\}/gm, e[o]);
         return n
      },
      o = function (t) {
         var e = t.selection.getNode(),
            o = "",
            r = "SPAN" == e.tagName && "fnoteWrap" === t.dom.getAttrib(e, "class"),
            i = "fnoteWrap" == e.className ? e.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") : e.childNodes[0];
         r && (o = e.name || decodeURIComponent(e.childNodes[0].getAttribute("data-content")) || ""), t.windowManager.open({
            title: "Insert Contents",
            size: "normal",
            body: {
               type: "panel",
               items: [{
                  type: "textarea",
                  name: "name",
                  multiline: !0,
                  minWidth: 520,
                  minHeight: 100
               }]
            },
            buttons: [{
               type: "cancel",
               name: "cancel",
               text: "Cancel"
            }, {
               type: "submit",
               name: "save",
               text: "Save",
               primary: !0
            }],
            initialData: {
               name: o
            },
            onSubmit: function (e) {
               var o, r, a, c, l = e.getData().name,
                  s = '<span class="fnoteWrap" id="#wk_ft{FOOTNOTE_INDEX}" contenteditable="false"><button type="button" class="fnoteBtn" data-content="' + l + '">{FOOTNOTE_INDEX}</button></span>',
                  f = t.getDoc().querySelectorAll(".fnoteBtn"),
                  u = f.length,
                  p = (r = t.selection.getNode(), a = function (t) {
                     var e = !1;
                     return (e = [].filter.call(t.parentNode.children, function (n) {
                        return n.previousElementSibling === t ? e = !0 : e
                     })).map(e => Array.from(e.querySelectorAll("fnoteBtn").length) > 0 ? $node.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("fnoteBtn") ? $node.nextElementSibling.children.children : e.querySelectorAll(".fnoteBtn") : "BODY" === t.nodeName ? [] : a(t.parentNode))
                  }, c = function (t, e) {
                     if (!e) return !1;
                     if (e) return $node;
                     var n = null;
                     return e.children.forEach(function () {
                        e && (n = c(t, this))
                     }), n
                  }, function (t, e) {
                     for (var n = a(e); 0 !== n.length;) {
                        var o = c(t, n);
                        if (null !== o) return o;
                        n = a(n)
                     }
                     return n
                  }(".fnoteBtn", r));
               if (p.length) {
                  var d;
                  for (p = p[0], d = 0; d < u && p != f[d]; d++);
                  i < u ? o = n(s, {
                     FOOTNOTE_INDEX: $(f[i - 1]).html()
                  }) : (o = n(s, {
                     FOOTNOTE_INDEX: $(f[d]).html()
                  }), t.selection.collapse(0))
               } else o = n(s, {
                  FOOTNOTE_INDEX: u + 1
               }), t.selection.collapse(0);
               t.execCommand("mceInsertContent", !1, o), e.close(), Array.from(t.getDoc().querySelectorAll(".fnoteBtn")).forEach(function (t, e) {
                  t.textContent = e + 1, t.parentNode.setAttribute("id", "#wk_ft" + (e + 1))
               })
            }
         })
      },
      r = {
         register: function (t) {
            t.addCommand("footnotes", function () {
               o(t)
            })
         }
      },
      i = {
         register: function (t) {
            t.ui.registry.addToggleButton("footnotes", {
               icon: "fnote",
               tooltip: "Footnote",
               onAction: function () {
                  return t.execCommand("footnotes")
               },
               onSetup: function (e) {
                  return t.selection.selectorChangedWithUnbind("span.fnoteWrap", e.setActive).unbind
               }
            }), t.ui.registry.addMenuItem("footnotes", {
               icon: "fnote",
               onAction: function () {
                  return t.execCommand("footnotes")
               }
            })
         }
      };
   e.add("footnotes", function (t) {
      t.ui.registry.addIcon("fnote", '<img src="' + tinyMCE.baseURL + '/plugins/footnotes/img/fn.png">'), r.register(t), i.register(t)
   })
}();
```

**footnote.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var global = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve('tinymce.PluginManager');

    if (typeof Array.prototype.forEach !== 'function') {
        Array.prototype.forEach = function(cb){
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            cb.apply(this, [this[i], i, this]);
          }
        };
    }
    if (Object.defineProperty 
        && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor 
        && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent") 
        && !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent").get) {
        (function() {
          var innerText = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerText");
          Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "textContent",
           {
             get: function() {
               return innerText.get.call(this);
             },
             set: function(s) {
               return innerText.set.call(this, s);
             }
           }
         );
        })();
      }

    
    /**
     * 
     * @param str
     * @param data
     * @returns {*}
     */
    var replaceTmpl = function(str, data) {
        var result = str;
        for (var key in data) {
            result = result.replace(/\{(\/?[^\}]+)\}/gm,data[key]);
        }
        return result;
    };

    /**
     * 
     * @param editor
     */
    var open = function (editor) {
        var selectedNode = editor.selection.getNode(), name = '',
            isFootNotes = selectedNode.tagName == 'SPAN' && editor.dom.getAttrib(selectedNode, 'class') === 'fnoteWrap';

        var selectIndex = (function(){
            if (selectedNode.className == 'fnoteWrap') {
                var num = selectedNode.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                return num;
            }
            else {
                return selectedNode.childNodes[0];
            }
        }());

        if (isFootNotes) {
            name = selectedNode.name || decodeURIComponent(selectedNode.childNodes[0].getAttribute('data-content')) || '';
        }
        
        
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Insert Contents',
            size: 'normal',
            body: {
                type: 'panel',
                items : [
                    {
                        type:'textarea',
                        name: 'name',
                        multiline: true,
                        minWidth: 520,
                        minHeight: 100,

                    }
                ],
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    type: 'cancel',
                    name: 'cancel',
                    text: 'Cancel'
                },
                {
                    type: 'submit',
                    name: 'save',
                    text: 'Save',
                    primary: true
                }
            ],

            initialData: { name: name },
            onSubmit: function (e) {
                var newfootnoteContent = e.getData().name,
                    fixFootnoteContent = (function () {
                        return encodeURIComponent(newfootnoteContent);
                    }()),
                    htmlTemplate = '<span class="fnoteWrap" id="#wk_ft{FOOTNOTE_INDEX}" contenteditable="false"><button type="button" class="fnoteBtn" data-content="'+fixFootnoteContent+'">{FOOTNOTE_INDEX}</button></span>',
                    totalFootNote = editor.getDoc().querySelectorAll('.fnoteBtn'),
                    totalCount = totalFootNote.length,
                    html;
                
                        
                function findNextFD(node) {
                    var getNext = function(el) {

                        var nextAll = false,
                            elements;

                        nextAll = [].filter.call(el.parentNode.children, function (htmlElement) {
                            return (htmlElement.previousElementSibling === el) ? nextAll = true : nextAll;
                        });

                        return nextAll.map(v => {
                            if (Array.from(v.querySelectorAll('fnoteBtn').length) > 0) {
                                
                                $node.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('fnoteBtn') ?
                                    elements =  $node.nextElementSibling.children.children :
                                    elements =  v.querySelectorAll('.fnoteBtn');

                                return elements
                            }
                            else {
                                if (el.nodeName === 'BODY') return [];

                                return getNext(el.parentNode);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    var nextInDOM = function(_selector, el) {
                        
                        var next = getNext(el);
                        
                        while(next.length !== 0) {
                            var found = searchFor(_selector, next);
                            if(found !== null) {
                                return found;
                            }
                            next = getNext(next);
                        }
                        return next;
                    }

                    
                    var searchFor = function(_selector, el) {
                        if (!el) {return false};
                        if(el) {
                            return $node;
                        }
                        else {
                            var found = null;
                            el.children.forEach(function() {
                                if (el)
                                    found = searchFor(_selector, this);
                            });
                            return found;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    var currentClassNot_NextClass = nextInDOM('.fnoteBtn', node);

                    return currentClassNot_NextClass;
                }
                
                var nextFD = findNextFD(editor.selection.getNode());

                if(nextFD.length) {
                    nextFD = nextFD[0];
                    var foundIdx;
                    for(foundIdx = 0; foundIdx < totalCount; foundIdx++) {
                        if(nextFD == totalFootNote[foundIdx]) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (selectIndex < totalCount) {
                        // modify
                        html = replaceTmpl(htmlTemplate,{FOOTNOTE_INDEX : $(totalFootNote[selectIndex-1]).html()});
                    }
                    else {
                        // anywhere add
                        html = replaceTmpl(htmlTemplate,{FOOTNOTE_INDEX : $(totalFootNote[foundIdx]).html()});
                        editor.selection.collapse(0);
                    }

                } else {
                    // last add
                    html = replaceTmpl(htmlTemplate,{FOOTNOTE_INDEX : totalCount + 1});
                    editor.selection.collapse(0);
                }

                editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, html);
                e.close()
               
                // index realignment
                
                var fnoteBtn = Array.from(editor.getDoc().querySelectorAll('.fnoteBtn'));

                fnoteBtn.forEach(function(value,idx){
                    value.textContent = idx+1;
                    value.parentNode.setAttribute('id','#wk_ft' + (idx +1))
                })
               
            }
        });
    };
    var Dialog = { open: open };
    var register$1 = function (editor) {
        editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton('footnotes', {
            icon : 'fnote',
            tooltip : 'Footnote',
            onAction: function () {

                return editor.execCommand('footnotes');
            },
            onSetup: function (buttonApi) {
                return editor.selection.selectorChangedWithUnbind('span.fnoteWrap', buttonApi.setActive).unbind;
            }
        });
        editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem('footnotes', {
            icon: 'fnote',

            onAction: function () {
                return editor.execCommand('footnotes');
            }
        });
    };
    
    var register = function (editor) {
        editor.addCommand('footnotes', function () {
            Dialog.open(editor);
        });
    };

    var Commands = { register: register };
    var Buttons = { register: register$1 };

    function Plugin () {
        global.add('footnotes', function (editor) {
            editor.ui.registry.addIcon('fnote','<img src="'+ tinyMCE.baseURL + '/plugins/footnotes/img/fn.png' +'">')
            Commands.register(editor);
            Buttons.register(editor);
        });
    }

    Plugin();
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `findNextFD(node)` there is no variable named `$node` inside that function. Try it without the `$` in front of `node`, and add some logic to make sure `node !== null` at the beginning of the function for debugging.

If you are trying to use the jQuery function `$` make sure it is imported properly and that the `$` is defined.

Some [examples](https://www.quackit.com/jquery/tutorial/how_to_use_jquery.cfm):

```
// Select all "p" elements and write "Hello"
$( "p" ).text( "Hello" );

// Change the color of all "p" elements to red
$( "p" ).css( "color", "red" );

// Hide all elements with the ".shy" class
$( ".shy" ).hide();

// Show the element with the "#nav" id
$( "#nav" ).show();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: But maybe I misunderstood you.Can you describe in more detail on the code itself?

Comment: Hi James, in your code you have a function named `function  findNextFD(node)`, and a few lines down you attempt to access the parameter `node` in `$node.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('fnoteBtn')`, within the scope of the function there is no parameter named `$node`, there is only `node`. If you need to access jQuery on that, try doing `$(node).nextElementSibling.classList.xyz.etc.etc...` effectively you need to pass `node` to jQuery (the $) as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
I tried to do as you advised. I removed all the $ signs. But I got the error - Uncaught ReferenceError: node is not defined. Could you please write what else I can try?

Comment: How are you currently trying to get the "node". It seems the function has no access to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not very familiar with javascript, so I may not understand. Could you please update your answer and write how I should do it better?